# What's the difference between 'In a way of her own' or 'in her own way'?

Tags: difference, idioms, idiomatic-language

What's the difference between 'In a way of her own' or 'in her own way'?

I'm going to make an example for clarity.

> Brenda is always very funny, although **in a way of her own/in her own
> way**.

What I want to mean is that Brenda is funny in a peculiar way, so some people might not always find her funny, especially if they don't have an open mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the difference between your two suggestions is that one is idiomatic and the other isn't.

It would be natural to say:

> Brenda is funny *in her own way*.

We just wouldn't say "in a way of his/her own", as [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20her%20own%20way%2C%20in%20a%20way%20of%20her%20own%2C%20in%20his%20own%20way%2C%20in%20a%20way%20of%20his%20own&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20her%20own%20way%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20his%20own%20way%3B%2Cc0) demonstrates - the phrases just don't appear in the search.

However, I'm not sure the correct version of this idiom means everything you say you want it to. It essentially means that someone achieves the same end result as others, but their *method* or 'way' of doing it is different or unorthodox.

You said you want it to mean that "some people might not always find her funny". I'd say that was true of almost everyone, unorthodox or not. Not everybody shares the same sense of humour. Also, in your quotation, you say that Brenda is "*always very funny*". This seems at odds with what you are asking how to say. How can someone *always* be very funny if some people don't always find her so? Additionally, saying that someone is "funny in their own way" could also potentially mean that they are eccentric, unusual, and *unintentionally* funny.

If you are trying to say that Brenda's humour is unorthodox, and not everybody finds it funny but you do, I would suggest you say something like:

> Brenda has an unusual sense of humour, but I always find her very funny.

You might also say her humour is "unusual" or "offbeat".

Comment: I might say that someone was funny, clever, talented, etc 'in their own way' if I actually thought the opposite but didn't want to sound unkind.